# what's update_collections=None mean in tf.slim

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

the instructions in `layers.batch_norm` goes:

> Adds a Batch Normalization layer from http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167.

Can be used as a normalizer function for conv2d and fully_connected.

Note: when training, the `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` need to be updated.
  By default the update ops are placed in `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`, so they
  need to be added as a dependency to the `train_op`.

One can set `updates_collections=None` to force the updates in place, but that
  can have a speed penalty, especially in distributed settings.

it says

> set `updates_collections=None` to force the updates in place

. what does it mean by **in place**.